# Shortest path given beginning and end of a weighted graph

Tags: c++, graph

I have to read in a file to create a weighted graph. The shortest path must be found using input from the file. File will be structured as first line = numVertices and every line below that has 3 numbers given as : 0 1 2  where 0 is start of an edge, 1 is the end of the edge, and 2 is the weight. I've tried implementing an adjacency matrix when creating my graph but have had no luck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Have tried restructuring the way I read in my file and have also tried adjusting my findShortestPath function.

```
void createGraph(string file_name) //Function to create a graph based on a file, whose name is file_name.
{
    ifstream f(file_name);
    if (f.fail())
    {
        return;
    }
    string line;
    getline(f, line);
    int num = stoi(line);
    numVertices = num;

    int data[50][50];

    string line2;
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;

    while (!f.eof())
    {
        f >> num1;
        f >> num2;
        f >> line2;
        num3 = stoi(line2);
        data[num1][num2] = num3;

    }

}
//////////////////shortest path function

string findShortestPath(int start, int end)
{
    int data[numVertices][numVertices];
    int dist[numVertices];
    bool sptSet[numVertices];
    int parent[numVertices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        parent[0] = -1;
        dist[i] = INT_MAX;
        sptSet[i] = false;
    }

    dist[start] = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < numVertices - 1; count++)
    {
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
        sptSet[u] = true;
        if (sptSet[u] == end)
            break;

        for (int v = 0; v < numVertices; v++)
            if (!sptSet[v] && data[u][v] && dist[u] + data[u][v] < dist[v])
            {
                parent[numVertices] = end;
                dist[v] = dist[u] + data[u][v];
            }
    }
    printSolution(parent);
```

Output is not outputting shortest path and is printing random numbers.

Comment: [`while (!f.eof())` is evil.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) Consider using `while(f >> num1 >> num2 >> line2;)` instead. It won't enter the loop if any of the inputs fail for any reason.

Comment: [Fear the VLA.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) They are non-portable and potential stack-killers.

Comment: `string findShortestPath(int start, int end)` promices to return a `string`, but it doesn't look like it does. While a compiler will allow this, usually with a warning, the code it generates is questionable. I recommend replacing the return type with `void` or rethinking the function.

Comment: Speaking of warnings, a good compiler will tell you almost exactly what is wrong: *warning: variable 'data' set but not used*. Don't ignore the warnings. they are the first line of defense against logic errors. If you research and resolve them when the compiler alerts you to them, you generally save a lot of time debugging.

Answer (score 0):

In your `findShortestPath` function `data[numVertices][numVertices]` is not the same as the `data` variable in your `createGraph` function.

Look at this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/ or try finding other sources on scope of variables.

Comment: how could I call the data into findShortestPath?

Comment: you could make data a global variable (declare it outside any functions or main) and remove the declarations in both functions.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `findShortestPath` you have declared a local array called `data`, which is supposed to store the adjacency matrix data. However, you have never written any data into it! Consider passing the matrix as a function argument. Your function signature should look something like this:

```
findShortestPath(int** data, int numVertices, int start, int end)
```

Also, avoid using VLA as it is not part of the standard. Consider creating a two dimensional array on the heap using `new`. (and don't forget to do `delete[]` after you are done!)

Or you can use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, if you don't want to manage your array's lifetime manually.

Comment: It is an assignment and I am not allowed to change the findShortestPath function parameters. Trying to find another way.

Comment: @zman1 Use global variables then. Move your `int data[50][50]` to global scope.